# Como utilizar webview en android studio para no salir de un dominio

Tags: java, android

Tengo en MainActivity.java el siguiente código, pero quiero terminarlo para que no se pueda salir de youtube.es. La idea es que si se clica un enlace externo a youtube.es no pase nada, que se quede donde esta:
Gracias.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("https://youtube.es/");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea una clase WebViewClient donde definas que no cambie la url de la página a cargar

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("https://youtube.es/")) {
            /*No se modifique este url*/
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

llamas de esta forma la clase:

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score -1):

Se me ocurre hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // reload youtube here
    }
});
```